# Create URL shortcut programmatically in Android

Tags: android, shortcut

I am trying to find out how to create URL shortcut in Android home screen programmatically and couldn't find the answer. It was asked once on StackOverflow, but the only answer had nothing to do with the question and has -2 ranking. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void setShortcut(String url) {
        String query = Uri.encode(url, "UTF-8");
        browserIntent = new Intent(CATEGORY_BROWSABLE, Uri.parse(Uri.decode(query)));
        browserIntent.setAction(ACTION_VIEW);

        if (ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported(getApplicationContext())) {
            ShortcutInfoCompat shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "1")
                    .setIntent(browserIntent) // !!! intent's action must be set on oreo
                    .setShortLabel("Test")
                    .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.bg))
                    .build();
            ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(getApplicationContext(), shortcutInfo, null);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"launcher does not support short cut icon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I have tested this on emulator and it works and opens url in the Browser you can use `.setIntent(browserIntent)` method to set intent to a shortcut and in the code I have created browserIntent  which opens the url in a browser

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am developing custom launcher and I am getting that 
`ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported(getApplicationContext())` 

returns false for my launcher. Do you know by any chance what changes should I apply for my launcher in order to make it support request pin shortcuts?